# While true loop with only one prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a piece of code with a while loop, that I want to run until the user enters the string exit. However, I don't want the loop to be stopped for a repeat prompt after every loop cycle. How can I achieve this?

Currently the code loops correctly, however it does not respond to exit once in the while loop.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    prog_question = input("Enter exit to quit the heat tracker after a cycle.")
    while name == True:
        if prog_question == "exit":
            name = False
            break
        else:
            temperature_info = measure_temp()
            if temperature_info[1] == "No error":
                if int(temperature_info[0]) < int(check_temp):
                    heater("on",check_period*60)
                else:
                    heater("off",check_period*60)
            else:
                measure_temp()
```

Comment: Do you mean that do not show the message about "Enter exit.....", you can use ```prog_question = input("\r")``` to get the next command.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to let the user interrupt an infinite loop.
Your idea using `input` has the disadvantage that the user needs to actually input something on each iteration.

It might be more interesting to use `try/except` for that:

```
from time import sleep
try:
    print("Hit Ctrl-C to stop the program")
    while True:
        print("still running")
        sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("this is the end")
```

Or you could also have a look at the module `signal`.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the prompt to inside of the loop.

```
name = True

while name:
    prog_question = input("Enter exit to quit the heat tracker after a cycle.")
    if prog_question == "exit":
        name = False
        break
    else:

        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the input is asked after every round which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh I must have mis-read the question sorry. @Demi-Lune's answer should achieve the behavior you're after then.